# Which compiler is best for someone who just started learning C++?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction

I have started learning C++. Which compiler do I choose ? I am using Windows 7. Though i have been using Turbo C++, many people suggest that it is not a good compiler to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114860/which-is-the-best-c-compiler

Comment: Reverting the title like that is a very bad idea - it turns your quite specific question a yet another question with a meaningless title.

Comment: @DumbCoder He did say c++ right?

Comment: @quasiverse - So what is the problem ? The link discusses C++ compilers only.

Comment: @DumbCoder Yeah... I think something went wrong there. When I hovered my mouse above the link it said "best c compiler". Hmm... sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). They focus a lot on [expressive diagnostics](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html), which may be especially useful to beginners. However, I am not sure how far along they are, and if any important feature are missing yet.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio. Free editions are available as well. The compiler is integrated into an IDE, which is the most complete and intuitive around.

http://www.microsoft.com/germany/express/download/default.aspx

Comment: +1, there's no better compiler for learning on Windows than Visual Studio. It has everything you need on top of the compiler, in an easy to use package.

Answer (score 2):

I would always recommend Visual Studio- it has the best debugger and you're gonna need a lot of said debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux, g++ (gcc) would be an good choice.

In windows I personally would prefer [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP), but you could use [g++](http://www.mingw.org/) here too. Thats more an personal choice which IDE / compiler you prefer, as they all should fit your needs.

Comment: edited to add some links hope you don't mind ;)